# How to keep Sachi on Re: Hollow Fragment

Tags: sword-art-online-hollow-fragment

I just got Sachi (starting lvl 80) at the `Strait of the Offering` after talking to her 3 times. Where do I go next in the `Driogeer Skycaves Area`?

---

**Prerequisite**: You have to beat the main Hollow Area storyline and not have a party member before approaching her.

**Note**: She is in the `Alevaste Otherworld Area`. Teleport to `Weald of the Wandering Aspirant` and head *south* to `Hall of the Followers' Loyal Triumph`. Then go *southwest* to get to the `Strait of the Offering`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: You need to go to `Data Collection Ruins Interior` in the `Driogeer Skycaves Area`. Then proceed to the `Research Vault` from `Bio-Engineering Containment Vault`. This room will not have map data. Inspect a glowing glyph on the wall on the right-hand side of the hallway midway down. This will trigger the fight sequence against noble crystals and golems. After defeating the golems, you will finally get to play with Sachi in the Hollow Area.

**My Recommended Level**: 150

**Golem Fight Tip**: Save your AOE till this fight and tell her to withdraw at the beginning. Use party buffs as soon as the fight starts.